# Error on pancakeswap, web3 python

Tags: web3js, blockchain, web3.py, defi, pancakeswap

I try send transaction but i get error.
https://bscscan.com/tx/0x3e716bc5d0500e8284de39c809a0251d07b0b3648591bf09fbafbb4dea633a34

I use web3.py

```
tx_params = {
            'from': wallet,
            'gas': 650000,
            'value': 0,
            'nonce': w3.eth.getTransactionCount(wallet)
        }

print(tx_params)

function = router.functions.swapExactTokensForTokens(
    int(7 * 1e18),
    int(5 * 1e18),
    [Web3.toChecksumAddress('0xe9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56'),
    Web3.toChecksumAddress('0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c'),
    Web3.toChecksumAddress('0xe9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56')],
    wallet,
    int(time.time()) + 10 * 60)

transaction = function.buildTransaction(tx_params)
signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(
    transaction, private_key=private_key
)

txn_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
```

Tell me please, how can i solve my problem with error 'Insufficient input amount, i have 0.07bnb and 46usd in wallet

Comment: can you help me? telegram @artem15510

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to swap 7 BUSD to 5 BUSD, which makes no sense. Try actually swapping to another token instead of the same token.

Comment: but i want swap BUSD-BNB-BUSD

Comment: Can I ask why you want to essentially pay BUSD and get less BUSD? There is no problem in your code, however the Pancake router contract doesn't allow such thing, so you will never get it to work.

Comment: I want to create volume, i want do buy and sell operations, and i hope that it is possible in one transaction to protect yourself from manipulation

Comment: For example, i want buy 5 tokens and sell 5 token in one pair

Comment: I want get equal BUSD, i pay 7 and i get 7, i set min_output 5 but it is not important